# Get counts of rows for each joined table for each row in the main table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have three tables in my database. The central table in the star schema is **sendings** with a PK column called `id`. Each sending record can have zero or more rows in the tables **opens**.

```
sendings.id = opens.sending_id
```

Similarly, a third table called clicks have the following association to the sending table (one sending can have zero or more clicks):

```
sendings.id = clicks.sending_id
```

Both **opens** and **clicks** tables have their unique id column, called `id`. 
What I would like to have *in one query*, is the count of all associated opens and clicks for each sending. The following query does not seem to meet that demand.

```
select s.id,
    count(o.id) as open_count,
    count(c.id) as click_count
from sendings s
left join opens o on s.sending_id = o.sending_id
left join clicks c on s.sending_id = c.sending_id
group by s.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select s.id,
       count(distinct o.id) as open_count,
       count(distinct c.id) as click_count
from sendings s left join
     opens o
     on s.sending_id = o.sending_id left join
     clicks c
     on s.sending_id = c.sending_id
group by s.id;
```

`count()` just counts the number of non-`NULL` values.

In general, a more performance solution is either correlated subqueries or aggregation before the `join`:

```
select s.id, o.open_count, c.click_count
from sendings s left join
     (select o.sending_id, count(*) as open_count
      from opens o
      group by o.sending_id
     ) o
     on s.sending_id = o.sending_id left join
     (select c.sending_id, count(*) as click_count
      from clicks c
      group by c.sending_id
     ) c
     on s.sending_id = c.sending_id;
```

Note that the outer `group by` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Which of the 2 solutions would you go with? I wasn't that off on the first, but `distinct` was missing and I was wondering why do I get similar numbers.

Comment: @disasterkid . . . If your counts are larger than you can count on your hands, then go with the second solution.